# I can't save Sample Result Save Configuration in apache Jmeter

Tags: apache, configuration, jmeter

I try to save Sample Result Save Configuration that I checked.
But after the click on save button and restart of Jmeter Sample Result Save Configuration that I checked is not saved.

So i referred to [Apache Default Configurations](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#defaults) link, (14.1, 14.1.2), I try to convert the Default Configuration to which I want to check at the Listener Config pop-up.

But it also failed.
How can i change Sample Result Save Configuration?

Comment: Can you attach a picture of the said element you have problem with? Because it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JMeter 2.11 and find the issue too. Also tried JMeter 2.13, but unfortunately it didn't help either. Since jmx file is actually a xml file, so I open it with notepad++ edit it directly and it finally works.

I know this is not a good solution, but it can be used as a workaround. Will keep you updated if I find better solution.

Comment: Hi @guswjd, the problem is related to Java version. When I use Java 1.8.0_51 (Oracle), both JMeter 2.11 and 2.13 have the 'cannot save result' issue. Then I noticed that XML parser is mentioned in file saveservice.properties, and related packages are imported from Javaio, so I thought it may have something to do with java version. Thus I switched to an old version 1.7.0_25, problem solved. Still not sure why the newer java version doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an issue, Atleast I am not having it.I am able to save the changes in sample results save configurations.

If you are not able to save there is workaround. Please edit user.properties under
/bin/ directory of jmeter and restart it. it will work